# Include files in ridl

Tags: delphi, idl

The Delphi project I'm working on requires me to create a very large type library in order to add COM support.  The problem is with the type library/ridl editor in Delphi is that it becomes difficult to manage (from a programmer point of view) such a large file,  and I'd like to split it along functional lines.  The problem I have is that I cannot see a way to include one ridl file in another.  I'm aware of the importlib function,  but I also cannot find a way to create more than one type library in the same project, or create a tlb file from within delphi.  Can anyone give me ideas on how to better manage this?

Answer (score 1):

Standard IDL has an `include` statement for pulling in other files into the TypeLibrary compilation.  RIDL stands for **REDUCED** IDL, so it might not support it, though.  You will have to try it and see.

Comment: Unfortunately ridl doesn't support it.  The only include mechanism in ridl is to import another type library.